# thread_local issues while using OpenMP with C++11 on Mac OS

Tags: c++, macos, g++, openmp, thread-local

I am facing issues while trying to compile my code which has OpenMP pragmas
After reading the answer [here](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) I was able to bypass OpenMP issues but now I face thread_local not found errors

I am running this command

```
g++ -Xpreprocessor -fopenmp -O3 cgrpt1.cpp -o cgrpt -lomp
```

And getting the following error message

```
cgrpt1.cpp:9:9: error: unknown type name 'thread_local'
        static thread_local std::default_random_engine generator(omp_get_thread_num() +
```

I tried using

```
-std=c++11
```

flags but it did not help.

Here are my compiler details -

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
(base) rajaskejriwal@Rajass-MacBook-Air a1_12236368 %
```